# How to add border around each refiner boxes - css?

Tags: css

How to change the look and feel on the search refiner part for each refiner box? I am trying to put border around each refiner box.

I tried adding border via developer tool using css style but it doesn't appear. Any idea why (I tried `!important`) using css for `.ms-ref-refiner` control did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did exactly what you mentioned and it worked great for me.  Did not need to use `!important` either.  I also tried inline styling to a specific refiner and worked there as well.

[image]

[image]

If this still doesn't work try applying directly to a single refiner via inline styling or using id like `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl00_csr1`.